# How can I remove the Whitespace of this PHP Code?

Tags: php, joomla, maps, whitespace

The whitespace on the following GoogleAPI (Map) link needs to be removed.
This is the code that generates the `<script>` that is placed in the `<head>`.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=<?JComponentHelper::getParams('com_ohanah')->get('maps_api_key_js')?>"></script>
```

The complete URL the code above generated is the following:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key= CENSORED
```

The issue here is the generated code has a whitespace of one character that needs to be removed.

Comment: `<?trim(JComponentHelper.............)?>`

Comment: What/where is the text being echoed/printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `trim` here. This will safe the trouble if you get some strange characters on the right and the left side:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=<?trim(JComponentHelper::getParams('com_ohanah')->get('maps_api_key_js'))?>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the following `str_replace()` function to your URL

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key= CENSORED";
$cleanUrl = str_replace(" ", "", $url);
```

cleanUrl will outpu

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=CENSORED"
```

Answer (score 0):

the safest way to do it is by using ltrim :

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=<?ltrim(JComponentHelper::getParams('com_ohanah')->get('maps_api_key_js'))?>"></script>
```

Hope it helps!